# bi-directional scroll with fixed headers

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

i would like to realize a bi-directional scroll view with fixed headers. For example the way you can find it in an excel-sheet:

[image: Text]

Anyone knows a package or a widget I could use for that?
Or would I have to implement such a logic by myself? 
And if that should be the case, could you give me some hints on where to start?

The only useful thing I found was this: https://pub.dev/packages/bidirectional_scroll_view
But this solution doesn't support headers.

I hope you have a great day !
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution making use of the `scrollListener` provided by the `BidirectionalScrollBiewPlugin`:

```
ScrollController _horizontalController = ScrollController();
ScrollController _verticalController = ScrollController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      BidirectionalScrollViewPlugin(
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 20),
          width: 1000,
          height: 1000,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('test asdasd asdqwdqwdqeqweqw eqweqeqweqweqwe'),
              Text('test asdasd asdqwdqwdqeqweqw eqweqeqweqweqwe'),
              Text('test asdasd asdqwdqwdqeqweqw eqweqeqweqweqwe'),
              Text('test asdasd asdqwdqwdqeqweqw eqweqeqweqweqwe'),
            ],
          )
        ),
        scrollListener: directionalScrollListener,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 18,
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
        child: ListView(
          controller: _horizontalController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: List.generate(200, (index) {
            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 2, bottom: 2),
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: 20,
        color: Colors.white,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
        child: ListView(
          controller: _verticalController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: List.generate(200, (index) {
            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2, top: 5, bottom: 5),
              child: Text(index.toString()),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```